# Can a single sentence be made using words to, too, and two consecutively (one after the other) in the same sentence properly?

Tags: english, open-ended

Without any restriction, can a ***single sentence*** be written or spoken  using the words "to", "too", and "two" in the same sentence consecutively used (one after the other) and be proper?

Please explain and write your ***example sentence*** if this is possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle or related to puzzling.

Comment: @Deusovi In any case, they migrated from the other site and thought it more appropriately belongs here instead. I started it where I felt it was appropriate to put it and then the moderators there told me otherwise. I really do not care what you all do with it at this point so feel free to do as you wish... my perspective was this is a simple question related to English and too simple and to puzzling for English so they moved it here. It sounds like moderators need to ensure the questions are appropriate before being moved to other communities.

Answer (score 9):

Peter: I won the game! I got to 2 points first!
Paul: But I got to two too!

Comment: I like the question, so I will add another permutation. "I'm giving two candies to all the trick-or-treaters with cute costumes." "Well, don't give two to too many or we'll run out."

Comment: Or how about "The Leafs beat the Blackhawks." "They beat the Bruins too: two to one." Then: "I gave away all my spare change." "Me too, to two guys on the street corner." That's four out of the six possible permutations of the three words. The question is now whether any permutation of the three is *not* possible.

Comment: "I had to upchuck after the party." "I had to too, two times."

Answer (score 9):

"I think the number six horse ate an apple before the race."

"I saw them give one to two too."